# Do I need a firewall with Orbot on an Android?

Tags: firewall

I've been using Tor and Orbot on my laptop and Android for almost a year and I'm totally satisfied on both devices.

On my laptop, I run an aftermarket firewall that I've used for many years, and it doesn't conflict with Tor. However, I'm curious if I should run one with my Android? If yes, which one?

I downloaded a NoRoot firewall app recently, but after configuring it, it wouldn't allow some apps to open, and it slowed the internet even more. That app also states that it operates like a VPN.

Suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, just to check: you're running Orbot on a laptop?

Comment: Yes, I am, but my question is pertaining to Orbot on Android...

Comment: Does https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/13946/orbot-apps-vpn-mode-vs-tor-everything-on-rooted-device-which-is-better/13950#13950 cover your question?

Comment: I got tired of waiting, and I didn't find a "Tour" button/link on the Tor Project page. After searching Google Play Store, especially for, "firewall for Tor" and coming up with Tor, Orbot, Orfox and assorted browsers and VPN selections, I gathered there aren't any. So I installed a very good cleaner with antivirus.  So far, so good!

Answer (score 0):

While waiting for an answer here, I did some of my own homework: in short, I've learned that many programs for laptops and desktops don't make good phone apps. While I absolutely love Tor, I finally found the problem I was having - while Tor was installed, a malware file, "10008_1.jar" kept downloading, then disrupting most all of my internet functions. I've had to uninstall Orbot and use another VPN. If this problem is found and cured, I'll gladly return to Tor/Orbot.

Comment: Where did you get Orbot from?

Comment: Do not download Orbot from unofficial sites. It's really dangerous. Here is the link: https://guardianproject.info/apps/orbot/

Comment: didt work for me
10008_1.jar keeps downloading D=
is parented with 2 folders: GANYUN and BEAUTY SNAP
Beauty Snap is an app in Palay Store but there is no uniinstall option
D=======

Comment: I'd love to get a sample of `10008_1.jar` for analysis. This sounds like your phone is infected, though...

Comment: Here is an update: since my last post, I became frustrated with my phone and did a factory reset - cured the existing problems... by the way, the .jar file was associated with gungyun, my stock camera. Just this week, I downloaded Orbit from Google Play Store, but it wouldn't function. My first download was directly from torproject.org. Maybe I should try another download from them directly?